# Deleting an empty folder, recursive PHP function returns not empty

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the function below to delete all files and folders from a given folder

```
function deleteFolder($dir){
    if(file_exists($dir)){
        $it = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($it,\RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

        foreach($files as $file) {
            chmod($file->getRealPath(),0755);
            if ($file->isDir()){
                rmdir($file->getRealPath());
            } else {
                unlink($file->getRealPath());
            }
        }
        rmdir($dir);
    }

}
```

but when use to one of a folder name `utso-pulgada-pd-loader-90ee46f149c9` it returns `not empty` even by deleting all files inside manually still returns not empty

Folder: utso-pulgada-pd-loader-90ee46f149c9

```
utso-pulgada-pd-loader-90ee46f149c9
    BUilder.php
    Patcher.php
    Loader.php
```

delete manually

```
unlink('utso-pulgada-pd-loader-90ee46f149c9/Builder.php');
unlink('utso-pulgada-pd-loader-90ee46f149c9/Patcher.php');
unlink('utso-pulgada-pd-loader-90ee46f149c9/Loader.php');
rmdir('utso-pulgada-pd-loader-90ee46f149c9');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your deleteFolder() is not returning anything.

Comment: @ascsoftw what you mean? the only job of that function is to delete all files, no return expected.

Answer (score -1):

maybe better to use recursive function. in your case it would be like this:

```
function deleteFolder($dir){
    if(file_exists($dir)){
        $it = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($it,\RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

        foreach($files as $file) {
            chmod($file->getRealPath(),0755);
            if ($file->isDir()){
                deleteFolder($file->getRealPath());  
                rmdir($file->getRealPath());
            } else {
                unlink($file->getRealPath());
            }
        }
        rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

We checked if the current file is a directory, then call the `deleteFolder` function with the directory path. When you call it it will remove all the files inside the directory then come back to the function and remove the directory itself.

Note: didn't test it

Comment: tried something like that, if directory then delete all files inside it, but unfortunately, did not work, throw me this error  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct

Comment: actually no need to re run the function by calling back the function, the RecursiveDirectoryIterator will do the job on scanning all the files and folders inside the given folder

Comment: Yes of course you can use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and many other options, but I just mentioned the problem with your code that I thought you need to figure it out why it doesn't work.